# Where to create directory for importing over network link?

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-11g, import

While using data pump import over network link in Oracle:

```
    impdp test/test@db10g tables=SCOTT.EMP network_link=REMOTE_SCOTT 
    directory=TEST_DIR remap_schema=SCOTT:TEST
```

Where are we creating directory object (TEST_DIR, for the above example)? On source or target database? Or both?

Answer (score 1):

impdp with network_link, `TEST_DIR` directory needs to be created at local. In your example where @db10g database is running.